# Why there is no favorite answer tag on answers?

Tags: support, feature-request

Just going through some questions, I realized that some of the questions do not make any sense at all although the answers do.

So why there is no favorite tag on answers? What if someone wants to make it a favorite answer?

Comment: @owlstead:What about other users, such as I am looking for a question which is already by asked some other user and I want to make that answer my favorite answer.?

Comment: I am unsure of what in this context "favorite" means, can you elaborate? Like the favorite question star?

Comment: You can upvote the answer.  When you come back later (presumably because you favorited the question), the upvoted answers readily stand out.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to be notified of edits to the answer?

Comment: @BenVoigt:Very late comment but appreciate that too. No I was asking that what if I want to make some answer only favorite and not the question, but as you can see I got my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be new answers that make more sense. Actually that happens a lot especially on questions with high vote counts. Instead of focusing on an answer you *already* know, it is better to quickly browse through the answers to see if there are important updates.

Comment: what about the answers that got a 'Reversal' badge? Some questions are simply an abomination and the only reason to go to them is because somebody took the time to write an awesome answer on them. Making the question a favorite in this case seems just wrong; they might get the 'favorite' or 'stellar' badge not because their question is great but because they got a great answer

Comment: @Erik Agreed, but I think the main focus is about finding good answers, and less about mistakes in the gaming system. If answers get a reversal badge then it will draw more attention and possibly other / better answers. The gaming system is means to an end. And yes, it is far from perfect.

Comment: So what? There may also be new questions that make more sense. Still I can make a question a favorite. Sometimes it's really hard to find the correct answer, because it's not the accepted one which is at the top and it needn't have so many votes. Actually, your argument is **pro** favorites on answers: what if a new answer is the best, but nobody has ever realized and the top answer has already 1000 votes?

Comment: @Erik If the question got a great answer, then, in a way, it was a great question.

Comment: @ThomasWeller This comparison goes awry when you note that you also get updates on answers if you mark a question as favorite. So you would only gain an advantage on a favorite answer if you are not interested at all in the other answers. Without the question favorite we would not have a favorite system to begin with.