# Make answers I have up-voted more visible to me

Tags: feature-request

Very similar suggestion to the one I made here:
[Make my own answers more visible to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357978/make-my-own-answers-more-visible-to-me)

If I have previously given an answer a thumbs up, it should be pushed to the top of the list for me, or some strong indicator above the fold to indicate I have previously given 1 or more answers a thumbs up.

Helps when you return to a question in the future to quickly see the answer(s) that you found most helpful/best.

Example, I gave Carl Mercier's answer an up-vote, about 6th on the list. Should be shunted to the top when I view the question later: 
[ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list)

Comment: Since you can't favorite  specific answers, I think this suggestion is not bad.

Comment: The better feature might be to favorite specific answers. I don't think voting should change the sorting of answers across all questions for everybody, for this specific case. I think many more people would find the change of sorting confusing and annoying.

Comment: [Old request to favorite answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252203/why-there-is-no-favorite-answer-tag-on-answers) from April 2014.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there is no favorite answer tag on answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252203/why-there-is-no-favorite-answer-tag-on-answers)

Comment: Please don't, ever, implement that, or make it a opt in setting buried deep in the profile.

Comment: Just want to give myself a pat on the back for this. My browser got wiped, so lost my little js script. After a couple days without it, already had cases where I wished I hadn't been lazy and just came back here and grabbed the code again. So here I am.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add a javascript injector extension to your browser and add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        //moves my own answers to the top
        var el = $('div.user-details').find('a[href="/users/3093731/andrew"]');
        if(el.length){
            el.closest('div.answer').css('border', '2px solid green');
            $('#answers').prepend(el.closest('div.answer'));
        }

        //moves answers I've up-voted to the top
        var el = $('.js-vote-up-btn.fc-theme-primary');
        if(el.length){
            el.closest('div.answer').css('border', '2px solid green');
            $('#answers').prepend(el.closest('div.answer'));
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Will push answers to the top of the page, at least answers that are on the first page of answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Helps when you return to a question in the future to quickly see the answer(s) that you found most helpful/best.

If you want to revisit certain answers, use a bookmark. We can link directly to answers (via the "share" link).

The voting order for answers is important; it's what makes voting *matter*. It allows us to (in theory) quickly identify content that has been reviewed as being good and content that is decidedly less than good.

Overriding this order, even if it's visible only to yourself, isn't helpful. It makes it too easy for you to ignore potentially better answers. And that's more important in the long run. You never know when you might run across something you hadn't considered.

If you want to revisit answers you like, that's fine. But that shouldn't be done by rearranging vote ordering.

Comment: I don't think you're capable of determining what is or isn't helpful and more important for OP.

Comment: @Oleg: And yet, that is the very foundation of SO, is it not? That voting will determine the best questions/answers? Is not the whole point of the site determining what is and is not helpful for others? Isn't that the reason why ordering by vote totals is the default view for a question's answers?

Comment: It determines (and even that not perfectly)  the best for *most* others. If what helped *me* is the fourth most upvoted answer then that is the best answer for me. All of that is beside the point, OP said that it's helpful, unless you know better than him what goes on inside his head you can't claim that it isn't.

Comment: @Oleg: The fact that someone believes something will be helpful to them doesn't mean that it actually is helpful to them. Psychology gives us plenty of examples of that. That's not to say that our judgement is guaranteed to be superior, of course. But the fact that someone says that something would be helpful to them is not by itself sufficient reason to add a feature to the site.

Comment: @Oleg what about questions on which you upvote more than one answer?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Make the number of upvotes a secondary order or something? Doesn't really mater, it's useful to OP, plenty of reasons not to implement it, Nicol's claim that something that *is* helpful to OP is *not* helpful to OP is not one of them.

Comment: Bookmarking an answer doesnt help see answers ive upvoted, this answer is not helpful. Added a helpful answer with helpful code, that solves the issue of wanting a feature I think would be helpful :)

Comment: @Andrew: "*Bookmarking an answer doesnt help see answers ive upvoted, this answer is not helpful.*" Sure it is. You made a feature request. My response was that it is a bad feature which should not be implemented, and I explained why it shouldn't. You may not *like* that answer, but it is helpful to the purpose of your question.